# How to put several diagrams in one row?

Tags: arrays

Here are my codes for four arrays. Is there a way to put four diagrams together in the same row instead of put one of them above the other without exporting them as images?

```
(a)\begin{displaymath}
\leftline{\xymatrix{ a \ar[r] & 0  \\
    b \ar[ru] & 1  \\
    c \ar[ruu] \space &  }}
\end{displaymath}

(b)\begin{displaymath}
\leftline{\xymatrix{ a \ar[rd] & 0  \\
        b \ar[r] & 1  \\
        c \ar[ru] \space &  }}
\end{displaymath}

(c)\begin{displaymath}
\leftline{\xymatrix{ a \ar[r] & 0  \\
        b \ar[ru] & 1  \\
        c \ar[ru] \space &  }}
\end{displaymath}

(d)\begin{displaymath}
\leftline{\xymatrix{ a \ar[r] & 0  \\
        b \ar[r] & 1  \\
        c \ar[ruu] \space &  }}
\end{displaymath}
```

Comment: We need a minimum working example which compiles for exact assistance.  In general, I would try either tabular or minipage environments.  But you have user defined commands in your code snippet and it will not compile as is.  It appears that you are constructing commutative diagrams so I would suggest you look at tikz-cd

Comment: Yes! My friend also told me to use tikz. And I'll try tubular and minipage. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a MWE which puts your diagrams in a row.  I have put together a very quick solution, however someone will probably provide an efficient version.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xypic}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\begin{minipage}{1in}
(a)\begin{displaymath}
\leftline{\xymatrix{ a \ar[r] & 0  \\
    b \ar[ru] & 1  \\
    c \ar[ruu] \space &  }}
\end{displaymath}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{1in}
(b)\begin{displaymath}
\leftline{\xymatrix{ a \ar[rd] & 0  \\
        b \ar[r] & 1  \\
        c \ar[ru] \space &  }}
\end{displaymath}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{1in}
(c)\begin{displaymath}
\leftline{\xymatrix{ a \ar[r] & 0  \\
        b \ar[ru] & 1  \\
        c \ar[ru] \space &  }}
\end{displaymath}
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{minipage}{1in}
(d)\begin{displaymath}
\leftline{\xymatrix{ a \ar[r] & 0  \\
        b \ar[r] & 1  \\
        c \ar[ruu] \space &  }}
\end{displaymath}
\end{minipage}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use something as follows to put 4 figures in the same row.

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=1in]{image}} 
\hspace{0.2cm} %inbetween
\subfloat[ caption]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=1in]{image}}
\hspace{0.2cm} %inbetween
\subfloat[ caption]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=1in]{image}}
\hspace{0.2cm} %inbetween
\subfloat[ caption]{\includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=1in]{image}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I've tried subfloat but it only works when those diagrams are actually "images". I want to keep my code in there so I guess tabular and minipage are probably the proper way to put them in one row. Thank you though :)